# MySQL Import Dump per Console

Tags: mysql, import

i try to import a sql dump via console to a database:

```
mysql -u admin -p password -D targetdbname < /var/www/vhosts/domainname.de/httpdocs/sp.sql
```

Then i had to provide password,- but the password i input is
not valid... Access denied for user admin@localhost (using password: Yes)

But

mysql -u admin -p password targetdbname

works, password correct.

??

Comment: There is no space allowed: `-ppassword` or `-p'password'` are correct, `-p password` is not.

Answer (score 0):

You should just write `-p` and don't specify a password at all, because it is not secure at all.

E.g. if you are on linux then users can just execute the command `history` and et voilà... they see your password in cleartext.